# How to binding the value in directive

Tags: vuejs2, directive

I want to create a directive for auto add the icon inside the button.
When user click on it.

But How to pass the loading value(it's boolean data) from the parent object?

```
Vue.directive('loading', {
    bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
        if (binding.value) {
            var loadingElement = Vue.extend({
                props:['isLoading'],
                template: '<span class="loading" v-if="isLoading"><fa-icon :icon="[\'fab\', \'facebook-f\']"></fa-icon></span>',
            });
            var loadingComponent = new loadingElement({
                propsData: {
                    isLoading: binding.value
                }
            });
            loadingComponent.$mount();

            el.appendChild(loadingComponent.$el);
        }
    },
    update: function (el, binding, vnode) {
        el.disabled = binding.value;
    }
});
```

I want `isLoading: binding.value` data is bind from the parent.